# Make Angular Library ( Built with v13) support in applications with older Angular versions ( At least angular 10 and above )

Tags: angular, angular11, angular-library, angular13

I am currently creating Angular Library with Angular 13.2.0. But I want the library to be used in my office projects which are in Angular 10. How do I deal with that, Gradually changing peerDependency I found that Angular application built with version 12 would support the library but not with Angular 11 and Angular 10.
I have included the error shown in Angular v11 below.

[image: This is the error in Angular version 11]

Comment: Have you found any solution for this? Currenly I am facing this issue